# Add SVN_AUTHOR and SVN_COMMIT_MESSAGE as env var in JENKINS

Tags: java, svn, jenkins, continuous-integration, environment-variables

In my **JENKINS** job configuration I'm sending an email to developers when a build is done.

In this mail I send  : `$PROJECT_NAME` `$BUILD_NUMBER` `$BUILD_STATUS` `$BUILD_URL` and `$SVN_REVISION`.

I use **Email Extension Plugin** v **2.38.1**.

In my email body, I want to add : `SVN_AUTHOR` and `SVN_COMMIT_MESSAGE`.

In **JENKINS** such env var doesn't exist. So is it possible to create them ? What plugin to use ?

Ismail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click the question mark next to **Content Token Reference**, it will show you a lot of things you can use.

Try this:

`${CHANGES_SINCE_LAST_SUCCESS, reverse=true, format="<b>Changes for Build #%n</b><br>%c<br>", changesFormat="<br>[%a] - (%r) %p<br> %m<br>"}`

This will produce output like:

> **Changes for Build #123**
>   [svn-author-name] - (svn-rev) path-to-changed-file
>   svn commit message here

Here is the relevant part from documentation:

> format - for each commit listed, a string containing %X, where %X is one of %a for author, %d for date, %m for message, %p for paths, or %r for revision. Not all revision systems support %d and %r. If specified, showPaths is ignored.
>   Defaults to "[%a] %m\n".

The above is relevant to [**Email-ext plugin**](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin) and will suffice for what you described in your question.

However, if you really want to make these available as **environment variables** available to other build steps and/or scripts, you would need to:

- Manually extract them from your SCM (probably using `svn log` command and some grepping/sedding/awking)
- Save the output to file, in format `param=value`
- Use **[EnvInject plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin)** build step to load the file as environment variables for other build steps/scripts